# Too much space on box - HTML

Tags: html, css

I created a box [here](http://www.iliveaccountable.com/weekly-coaching-videos/).

but the space is too much on the top and the bottom.

See image here:

[image]

How can I remove the extra spacing between top and bottom of the:
1.Title and the date 
2. The button and the text 
3. The button and the extra spacing below

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="col-1-3"><img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/iliveaccountable.jpg" alt="" />
<h3 style="font-family: 'Montserrat'; text-align: center;">TAKING IT TO THE SOURCE</h3>
<h4 style="font-family: 'Montserrat'; text-align: center;">11/13/2016</h4>
<a href="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/oldsite/iliveconnected-patterns/" target="_blank">
<button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
</a>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-1-3 {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
margin: 1%;
 border: 1px solid #dedede;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
border-radius: 7px;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-block{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-1-3 {width: 44%;}

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .col-1-3 {width: 94%;}

}
```

I just want to have enough space but this spacing are too much.

Comment: Using a [DOM inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#The_Inspector_DOM_explorer_and_CSS_editor) can help track down issues like this. Most modern browsers include one.

Comment: What worked for you...please consider accepting answer if it is of any help

Answer (score 1):

Make margin and padding 0 for all elements within div.col-1-3

check this snippets

```css
h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
.col-1-3 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 28%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.col-1-3 img {
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  margin: 0;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 44%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
  .col-1-3 {
    width: 94%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1-3">
  <img src="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/iliveaccountable.jpg" alt="">
  <h3 style="font-family: 'Montserrat'; text-align: center;">TAKING IT TO THE SOURCE</h3>
  <h4 style="font-family: 'Montserrat'; text-align: center;">11/13/2016</h4>
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.iliveaccountable.com/oldsite/iliveconnected-patterns/" target="_blank">
      <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Watch Video</button>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You can check it here and inspect element: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/weekly-coaching-videos/ your answer doesn't work.

Comment: There's stil space at the bottom.

Comment: there is some padding defined on col-1-3 ,remove it if you dont want it...i have just said padding-bottom as 0 ,so that there will be no space on the bottom...if you dont want any space take off whole padding

Comment: Is there any demo?

Comment: Updated the code but it seems there is still padding on the bottom. CHeck the page. iliveaccountable.com/weekly-coaching-videos

Comment: That would be the last thing that I want to remove the bottom space after the button.

Comment: @MatthewMatt You've got `<br />` elements in there. And still some margin on the button. I recommend using an HTML inspector.

Comment: you have got br's remove them and add this css .col-1-3 *{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
} ,there would be no space then...modified the code accordingly check it

Comment: I fixed the first one but the second one did not. What do you think am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean by the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Create additional CSS rules for `h3`, `h4` and `btn-block` in which you define settings for `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`. Start with value `0` for all and increase the values until you are satisfied with the result.

ADDITION after comments:

1.) you have an empty `p` tag between the image and the `h3` 
2.) You have a CSS rule for all `p` tags with a bottom margin of 20px (on line 278 of "style.css")

Comment: You can check it here and inspect element: http://www.iliveaccountable.com/weekly-coaching-videos/ your answer doesn't work.

Comment: see the addition to my answer

Comment: Is there any demo?

Comment: a demo of what ?  - create a snippet or a codepen, then I can work on it.